# COQ: How to use "<=" for Z and R in the same lemma?

Tags: coq

Suppose I already defined `floor` (from `R` to `Z`). Now I want to prove that `n <= x` implies `n <= floor(x)`, where `n : Z`, `x : R`.

I tried:

```
Lemma l: forall (n:Z) (x:R), (IZR n) <= x -> n <= (floor x).
```

but I'm getting the error `The term n has type Z while it is expected to have type R.`

How should I write this? Is there a way that I can use `<=` for `Z` and `R` simultaneously?

Answer (score 5):

In order to override the default interpretation of a notation, you can [open a notation scope locally](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#opening-a-notation-scope-locally) using `%key`:

```
Lemma l : forall n x, (IZR n <= x)%R -> (n <= floor x)%Z.
```